# Postgres offset limit query does not return if offset > last result

Tags: postgresql, heroku

A puzzle... I have two Postgres 9.3.9 databases. Let's call them 'production' and 'staging'.

I am doing a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id > start_id OFFSET 99 LIMIT 1
```

The problem lies in what happens when there are less than 99 items in the results.

On 'staging' the query returns zero rows.

On 'production' the query hangs and doesn't return.

I have experienced the same problem on the production db both via Django ORM code in a python console (via `heroku run`) and also using Postico GUI client remotely ...so it seems likely problem is something in the db config.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Make a request to the console postgres, if the request hangs, make parallel another request
"SELECT datid, query, query_start, waiting, state FROM pg_stat_activity;", show the result, I am not able to repeat your problem

Comment: do you know how to get psql to show the full content of a text column (eg the `query` column)...? this is on the production db so there's lots of rows and I can't tell what I'm looking at - the queries are truncated

Comment: Show truncated version.

Comment: I mean I can't tell which row is the relevant one and there's hundreds of rows

Comment: Check the status of your request, and requests to the table mytable.

Comment: Your are request make in psql console also hangs?